# Best way to prevent Ctrl+c on JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, copy, clipboard, jtextarea

I want to prevent copying the text from the `JTextArea`. What is the best approach to do that? I found a `KeyListner` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703951/how-can-i-prevent-ctrlc-on-a-jtextfield-in-java) but it didn't seemed best. I don't want to use a key listner for that. Is there a shortcut method/way that I can use?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a key listener?

Comment: @Juhana `KeyListener` should be avoided, a better approach would be to overload the defined key bindings as it would be a more guaranteed solution

Comment: Aside from the general user hostility, I'd note that this does not prevent copying by other methods, such as pasting the X11 primary selection.

Comment: *"I want to prevent copying the text"*  Why?  What do you hope to achieve by that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not tested, but I would simply override `copy()` and `cut()`:

```
@Override
public void copy() {
    // does nothing
}

@Override
public void cut() {
    // does nothing
}
```

Looking at the source code, it should work, since that's what JPasswordField does to prevent cutting/copying.

Comment: see answer by (@Azad) rest could be based on [(@camickrs) Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)

Comment: This sounds a better idea, since it should also deal with cut / copy invoked via menus ... if that is possible.

Comment: It would also work if the key binding is not Ctrl-C. And it would also prevent copying with the mouse only (which, at least in native apps, is possible under Unix)

Comment: How `copy()` called when I press Ctrl+c? Is there a keyBinding on JtextArea?

Comment: then methods implemented in Document(Xxx e.g. Listener) are/could be responsible, better place for JTextComponents

Comment: +1 for that, but need to extend the `JTextArea` class for overriding. thanks any way

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**KeyBindings**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html):

```
textField.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control C"), "preventCopy");
textField.getActionMap().put("preventCopy", new AbstractAction(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          //do something else when user presses control+c
      }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this would work, as it leaves the original action in place to continue working

Comment: @MadProgrammer: It's working, however, I am totally refuse to prevent CTRL+C from copying, I don't wanna bother the user.

Comment: +1 user can also copy the text from menu, anyway new learning for the `keyBinding`, one feature no need to extend `JTextArea`. can you solve my [another problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652806/arabic-typesetting-font-slowers-my-jtextarea-jtextpane-and-jtexteditor) please.

Comment: @aquestion [I answered the other problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652806/arabic-typesetting-font-slowers-my-jtextarea-jtextpane-and-jtexteditor/17908014#17908014), see it.